# Is it safe to store code as text in a database with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, sql-injection

I am working on a web app for a university course final project. The project revolves around saving code snippets input by the user (actually that is the whole premise). I used EF Core for a code first database. The code is stored in a string. I know that any time you receive input text from a user, you are vulnerable to SQL injection and I can't help but feel that this problem would be compounded if the user entered SQL code to save (heck they might want to save a SQL injection attack).

I am not dealing with raw SQL queries, but rather a DbConext and Linq queries so I don't think I should have to worry about fixing those, just input sanitization. How can I make sure that any text entered by the user is stored safely and won't screw up my database? Still learning. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the Snippet Class

```
public class Snippet : DatabaseEntity
{
    public int SnippetId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Snippet() : base() { }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to save Snippets

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    context.Snippets.Add(snippet);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
}
```

My main concern is determining whether this is fine or if I need to protect myself more.

Comment: You'd need to show us all the code you are using to save the user input, and all the code you are using to execute their input. Many classes are safe from injection, so without seeing what you are doing we can't really comment.

Comment: It also depends on what you're planning to do with those snippets; if you're not planning to execute them and that are being inserted, and retrieved, by parametrised queries then they aren't going to pose any danger. If, of course, you are inserting the data and then giving the option for the user to retrieve the code and execute it (on the instance?), that is when you have problems.

Comment: @DaleK I updated the question with some code

Comment: @Larnu I am only performing CRUD operations with the code as text. No execution

Comment: If you aren't executing the code then there is no issue. It's just data